# Host a blog inside Hybris commerce

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

We are looking into hosting a blog within our Hybris commerce. So it would be rootdomain.com/blog. How can this be made possible? Hybris does not create a physical folder in the disc that can be converted to a web app for

Comment: Do you have a different blog platform like WordPress which you want to access using the same root domain? If that is your question, you can host the blog platform separately and just redirect `/blog` request to blog platform from your web server.

Comment: If you want to design the blog platform within the Hybris then I would suggest leveraging WCMS functionality. Think of templates and custom components.

Comment: You can create an ancillary page/static page with just one component i.e. Paragraph component. This would effectively act as a blog.